# Weird (japanese?) live action movie with man in full metal suit that fights giant creatures

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Now this one is tough, i have talked to so many people and i have tried to search so much.

I saw a film when i was a kid, it was this strangest thing. In my country the film was actually called "man of steel" / "Stålmannen" :In Norwegian (Though i do not know what title this film had in English, but in my language the film title translates directly to man of steel). The film is Asian i think, and it is about a man that can fly, and he fights huge creatures, like godzillas or something like that. Or huge robots like we see in Neon genesis. I think i can recall this man of steel wearing a full metal suit with helmet.

I can not seem to have found a godzilla movie that has a flying man beating him up. But that does not mean it isn't a godzilla movie or spin-off. This might also be a movie made around 1976-1980 to be a sort of Japanese take on Superman the movie or King Kong.

I remember far to little of the film, because i was very young when i saw it, and that was in the mid-late 80's. So it must of course have been made before this. The effects were not very good, and i bet this film/tv movie released on VHS was made between 1970 and 1988. I could rent this in the video store.

Hehe, i hope some other member here actually have seen this piece of art and can help me out.

Edit: This movie i'm looking for is not animated.

Edit 2: After getting a lot of help from you guys we might be on our way to narrow it down. Mirrorman seem to be the one that comes closest at the moment. But i can not seem to find a full size movie of this character. And he also is to big, i am almost certain the hero i am talking about was not monster size, or it can maybe be my brain tricking me since he is a normal man, then becomes big size as mirrorman. This i cannot say for sure, but mirrormans battles and suit do give me some flashbacks. And it does not seem to be ultraman.

Edit 3: Anyone know if Hong Kong ever made something like this? We have been focusing on Japan all the way.

Comment: When were you a kid? Would something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Hero_Series fit the bill?

Comment: This was in the mid-late 80's. 1985-89 when i saw this. I could rent this in the video store as a movie, it was not a television show. At least not what i saw. But when i now see stuff from metal hero, i think i can remember that this "man of steel" did have a full metal suit. This is probably why the film was called "man of steel".

Did they make a movie of metal gear?

Comment: The page Jaydee linked to does have a section for ["Theatrical releases"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Hero_Series#Theatrical_releases), you might try googling them each in turn to see if any images online match your memories.

Comment: My guess was going to be Ultraman as well. So this was a normal-sized man who fought giant creatures?

Comment: Yes, he was not as big as ultraman, that's for sure. If not my memories a re completely screwed. But ultraman does in fact look like what i saw. Huge fights in urban areas against big monsters.

Comment: Could you post the title as it was in your native language?

Comment: Any of these? http://www.japan-talk.com/jt/new/20-greatest-Japanese-superheroes 
It's particularly hard to find one that doesn't involve a hero that's also giant. Some of them even grow larger when it's time to fight the giant monster, like Mirrorman (I believe).

Comment: The 1973 film "Godzilla Vs. Megalon" featured Jet Jaguar, which was an Ultraman-like robot who could go from human-size to Godzilla-size and fly.

Comment: @Mandsome - If we knew what country or language you're talking about, it would help greatly.

Comment: Was it live-action or a cartoon?

Comment: @CreationEdge My native language is Norwegian. And it spells "Stålmannen". (Man of Steel)

Comment: @Omegacron My country is Norway. The country the film is made in, is what i don't know. I just think it was Asian, and if Asian, most likely Japanese. I don't know why i think this, but they most likely did not speak English and the main roles were probably Asian too. And the urban set pieces and the monsters i saw probably screamed Asian aswell.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySllO9PSG0s

Comment: Lots of similar characters on the Ultraman Wiki site - http://ultra.wikia.com/wiki/Ultraman_Wiki

Comment: i was wondering. What if this was not japanese. Has Hong Kong ever done anything like this?

Comment: I posted the question on Movies SE too. You never know.

Answer (score 7):

if the title is Man of Steel may I point you to the Taiwanese film adaptation of the Tokusatsu series "Super Robot Mach Baron'"? That has the alternate title of "Man of Iron" in English or "Iron Superman"
[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbLu9.jpg)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbLu9.jpg):

this is an episode from the original Japanese edit of the show

Is it also the Taiwanese/Thai/Japanese coproduction movie "MarsMen"? The Jumborg Ace character in the movie was design by the same person who designed Mirrorman
[image: Here's the character]

Answer (score 6):

The year you remember seeing it in is way off, but this sounds a lot like the 1998 Japanese live-action film [Dark Soldier D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Soldier_D). There aren't many good pictures from it online, but [an image of the robot](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51BJP8RG44L.jpg) on the DVD cover might ring a bell? It's about a soldier who was recruited to test an experimental armored suit, and then ends up using it to fight giant monsters. The monsters are huge, but the robot suit he pilots is not much bigger than a human. There are some pretty memorable moments - in the second "episode", he fights [a giant monster chicken](http://www.lockntoad.com/hrotia/DarkSoldier3.jpg), and then loses his arm in the battle (he gets a mechanical arm in the third part). In any case, this is a long shot, but your description immediately made me think of it.

Comment: Hey ;), Thanks for helping. But it can not be this, the movie i am looking for is not made this late. In 1998 i was already in my 20's. And i also read this is not based on anything prior, so it is not a remake either :(

Comment: @Mandsome That's too bad - you might enjoy this one anyway, so I hope it's not a total waste :)

Comment: Nah nothing here that tries to help me out is a waste. I might actually take a look at this if i can find it :D.

Answer (score 5):

After consulting with a friend who knows more about Japanese TV shows of that period, I have another candidate: 
The 1978 series [Dinosaur Corps Koseidon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur_Corps_Koseidon). This show features Koseider, a [hero in a suit with a helmet](http://ultra.wikia.com/wiki/Koseidon) who fights dinosaur-like monsters (so, similar to Godzilla). The monsters are mostly the same size as he is, but he does [fight giant monsters](http://ticra.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-1078.html):
[image: Koseider in his costume flying toward a giant monster named Ragout]

Comment: Wow this was a good suggestion. I have seen some clips of this now, and i don't think this is it. But a lot of it resembles what i have seen. I gotta say, that even though we haven't found the right movie yet, we are now digging into some of the weirdest stuff ever made :D. It's like a treasure hunt. When i see the photo you have linked, it does in many ways resemble what i have seen.

ON the other hand. Since this was on rental in my country, the logic is also that this probably was not a super rare tv show. It must have had a sort of appeal. I think.

Thanks so much for helping :D

Comment: @Mandsome You just might need to watch clips of every Japanese tokusatsu series ever made until you figure it out, then you can post your own answer :P

Comment: Haha :D... Yeah i knew this one would be tough. But it kinda seems odd if they just released a episode of something and called it "man of steel", and that i could hire it from a video store in a city with 4500 citizens. Though some years later they got the entire thundercats series on vhs and so on. But still.. Maybe.. But why "man of steel"?

Could this be something made in Hong Kong?

Answer (score 5):

Some other Japanese tv & movie suggestions:

Jet Jaguar (man sized flying robot, hijacked by Seatopians to lead monster Megalon....but breaks free from their control, then grows to giant size and assists Godzilla in battling Megalon & Gigan) appears in movie "Godzilla vs Megalon" (1973).

"Zone Fighter". 1973 Toho studios TV series & answer to Ultraman, and other henshin/transformation heroes such as Kikaider, Kamen Rider, etc. Giant Ultraman style hero, fights giants monsters, including cameos from Godzilla, King Ghidorah, & Gigan. Official Toho TV spin-off of Godzilla film series. (Maybe a movie have been edited togetherfrom episodes?)

"Red Man" 1972 Tsuburaya Productions...Ultraman looking hero, fought monsters. Very low budget! (Maybe a movie edited together from episodes?)
Other Tsuburaya 1970s tv series: "Jumborg Ace"; "Jumborg 9"; "Fire Man".

"Super Robot Red Baron" 1973, and it's 1974 sequel "Super Robot Mach Baron".
Somewhere in Asia, the 1974 series (Mach Baron) was adapted into an 86-minute feature film which used footage from the original series.

"Iron King". 1972. Ultraman like, & hero is assisted by hat/jacket cowboy character with whip he swings on to fight giant robots/monsters (cowboy that Indiana Jones is based on).

"Giant Robo", or English dub/edit known as "Johnny Sokko and His Flying Robot" 1967 tv series...In 1970, several episodes were edited together to create the 95-minute "Voyage into Space".

"Dinosaur War Izenborg" (1977) Tsuburaya. Both animated & live action, animated people in helmuts & super vehicles fight evil Dinosaurs, then become Izenborg, a sort of Ultraman-like giant hero. The first four episodes were released in the form of a movie edit titled "Attack of the Super Monsters".

Sky Rider (6th Kamen Rider: "Sky Rider" or 'The New Kamen Rider') flies, fights monsters. TV Series. Sky Rider Had a 1980 movie also: "Kamen Rider: Eight Riders vs. Gingaoh".

Answer (score 4):

Guyver was roughly from the 80's as well. This is the first episode of the anime which aired in ~1989.

---

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what i am looking for was not animated.

Comment: @Mandsome you should update your question as to me it shouts out animated due to the nature of the movie you describe.

Comment: Yes i updated my original post with more details now.

Comment: Each suggested original should be its own separate answer so mandsome can mark a specific answer as correct.

Comment: They actually made 2 Guyver live action movies, but they don't involve giant creatures. The first starred Mark Hammil

Answer (score 4):

Might it be *Tetsuo, The Iron Man*? This was a live action japanese cyberpunk movie with cheesy graphics, although the first Tetsuo movie did not come out until 1989. Here is the trailer for it:

Comment: hehe :D A few years ago when i tried to find the film, there was this guys that proposed this. Probably because of the title :D. But it's not this one, not even close. hehehe :D But thanks for helping :D

Answer (score 4):

Was it perhaps Infra-Man? I remember watching this one as a kid, around the same time you're talking about. I don't remember many details about the movie, though.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073168/

Comment: hahaha :D omg all these weird old asian films. No it is not this one :). But i might actually watch this "masterpiece" some day, as the whole movie is on youtube. ^^

Answer (score 4):

Could it be [Ultraman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraman)?  This was from the 60s.

[image]

Comment: Hey. No it's not ultraman. But thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 2):

I know what you are referring to.. its a series not a movie..

Sorry it's dubbed in Arabic

Comment: And what series is that?

Answer (score 2):

Spectra man is what you're looking for:

[image]

Comment: Spectreman is how you spell it I think

Answer (score 1):

[*Dinosaur War Izenborg*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur_War_Izenborg).

It's an old anime series 
We had it when we were kids but dubbed in Arabic (*الرجل الحديدي*, *The man of steel/man of iron*).

I hope this is what you were talking about.

Comment: Hi there. As this is animated, and not live action, it's probably not "the one", but partial matches are good to have as well! Could you [edit] your answer to explain how it matches? Such as providing summary, quotes etc. (Note that an other user already proposed that one but didn't go into much detail...)